# sql delete with join causes syntax error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to delete the  child table data using sql, but i am getting below error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax near: **'ON t1.foodUnit_relation_Id = t2.food_unit_relation_id WHERE
>   t1.id =7' at line 3**"

this is my query:

```
   DELETE t2.* 
   FROM food_details t1, food_units_relation t2 
   ON t1.foodUnit_relation_Id = t2.food_unit_relation_id 
   WHERE t1.id =7
```

Where:

- `food_details`  is a parent table & `food_units_relation`  is a child table.
- Column `food_unit_relation_id` of `food_details`
  refrences to field `foodUnit_relation_Id` of `food_units_relation` table

can any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the JOIN keyword.

You could do it without JOIN :

```
DELETE FROM food_units_relation
WHERE food_unit_relation_id IN (SELECT foodUnit_relation_Id FROM food_details WHERE id = 7);
```

Or with JOIN :

```
DELETE food_units_relation
FROM food_units_relation
JOIN food_details ON food_details.foodUnit_relation_Id = food_units_relation.food_unit_relation_id 
WHERE food_details.id =7
```

Comment: I tried the join on: Error: `Unknown column 'food_details.foodUnit_relation_Id'`

Comment: @Sundara You should know the correct column name - food_unit_relation_id, or food_unit_relation_Id, or whatever.